# Getting Context of a fragment

Tags: android, achartengine

I am developing an application to read spectrum data from a txt file and am using Achartengine for plotting the points. I am using a fragment and trying to add the GraphicalView returned by the  getView(Context context) method of the ScatterGraphPlot .java class  to the Linear Layout of the fragment. Actually I cannot figure out which context is to be passed to the getView (Context context) method to get the GraphicalView.
This piece of code is from mainactivity.java file for reading the file and adding the view

```
loadspec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadspec);
        loadspec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                filepath = filename.getText().toString();
                filepath = "/sdcard/" + filepath + ".txt";

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
                    String specData = "";
                    int channelVal = 1;
                    while ((specData = br.readLine()) != null) {

                                                       scatter.StringProc(specData, channelVal);
                        specData = "";
                        channelVal++;

                    }

                    br.close();
                    scatter.addPointsTochart(channelVal);

                    FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
                    ChartFragment CF = new ChartFragment();
                    FT.add(R.id.chart_fr, CF);
                    FT.addToBackStack("CF");
                    FT.commit();
                    //code for adding GraphicalView in the Fragment
                                //by calling the getView(Context context) method.



                }
```

As you can see there is a loadspec button which plot the spectrum after reading the .txt file 
Scatter.addPoints(int) will add points to the series
After adding the points the Fragment transaction is done and now I cannot figure out which Context is to be passed to getView(Context context)
This is the getView(Context context) method.

```
public GraphicalView getView(Context context)
    {
        chartview = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(context,dataset,mRenderer);
        return chartview;
    }
```

This is the ChartFragment class extending fragment class

```
package com.example.spectrumreaderfragments;

import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class ChartFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View v = inflator.inflate(R.id.chart_fr,container,false);
            return v;

        }


    }
```

Hope someone will help me out with this. Thanks in advance. Also let me know if any other part of the code is to be posted

Comment: getView is a method in the ScatterGraphPlot.java class which will return the GraphicalView which conatins the plot. It takes context as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getActivity()` method of the fragment to get the context.

So for,

```
public GraphicalView getView(Context context)
    {
        chartview = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(context,dataset,mRenderer);
        return chartview;
    }
```

This will work well to call view - `getView(getActivity().getApplicationContext())`.

**NOTE:**

Be careful where you're calling this, as `getActivity()` will return null if the fragment has been detached.